# Attachment page 404

Tags: attachments, 404-error

After I uploaded some files into the Media Library, I clicked "View attachment page" in "Attachment Details", but I got a 404 not found error. The URL is like `http://example.com/filename/` and there is an `attachment.php` in my theme.

How can I solve this?